# Simple email input store in database

Tags: database, forms, email, input

I'm trying to build a really simple form to store email adresses in the wp database for future newsletter purposes. What I have is just a single email input:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." required>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I would just like to store each inputted email adress in a custom table in a format 'email1@domain.com', 'email2@domain.com' etc. This would probably be easiest to work with.

What I tried so far:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = wp_newsletter;
    $data = array(
        'email' => $_POST['email']
    );
    $format = array(
        '%s'
    );
    $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );

    if($success){
        echo 'data has been saved'; 
    }
}
```

But even this simple code doesnt seem to work. No table is created and nothing is echoed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to create a table first before you can insert a row. You are trying to insert a row into an non existent table.

Comment: Also note that I believe WordPress has some reserved post variables you cant overwrite.

Comment: @stemie That makes sense, sorry I dont work with a database often. I created a table, now how would be the best way to create just a single row called emails, and the value for this would be an array of entered emails?